# Three.js Изменение текстуры

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

Как можно изменить текущую текстуру (установил программно) у 3d объекта, используя `textureObjLoader`?

```js
textureObjLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader(),
        map = textureObjLoader.load(`./models/${allTextures[i][0]}`);
        material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({map: map});
        objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();

        objLoader.load(`./models/${objects[i]}`, function (obj) {
            obj.traverse( node=>{if (node.isMesh) node.material = material});
            obj.name = names[i];
            scene.add(obj);
        });
```

Comment: ну вот вы устанивливаете параметр `map`, его и нужно обновить, для изменения текстуры в рантайме, а затем позвать `material.needsUpdate = true;`

Comment: @StrangerintheQ вот так?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ map = textureObjLoader.load(`./models/${result}`);
material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({map: map});
material.needsUpdate = true;

Comment: @StrangerintheQ То есть я хочу установить новую текстуру лишь определенному объекту, соответственно, использую `scene.getChildByName(имя объекта)`.

Comment: Да, похоже, я не могу проверить с телефона

Comment: @StrangerintheQ просто этот код не срабатывает((

Comment: я доберусь до компа и сделаю пример

Comment: определенной части зашруженной модели?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Смотрите, я хочу сделать слайдер с 3d объектами+ была возможность менять текстуры этих объектов. И отвечая на ваш предыдущий вопрос, текстура должна покрывать весь объект (точнее закрашивать его)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Для ясности картины скину ссылку на [репозиторий](https://github.com/CreativeRusBear/Three.js/tree/master/3D-Model-Slider)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы изменить текстуру y `THREE.MeshPhongMaterial` достаточно изменить параметр `map` и поставить флаг `needsUpdate` у уже существующего материала

```
   material.map = texture;
   material.needsUpdate = true;
```

Однако загрузка текстуры - асинхронная операция, и по этому выставлять эти параметры необходимо после загрузки изображения, в случае когда оно еще не загружено.

Я поправил функцию из Вашего примера и теперь при нажатии на круги у банана меняется текстура.

Вторым аргументом у метода `load()` в `textureLoader` идет колбек загрузки текстуры, я поместил в него код, который не создает новый материал и только меняю текстуру в уже существующем.

```
function changeTexture(i) {
    let colorBlocks = document.querySelectorAll('.color_scheme__block');
    colorBlocks.forEach((val) => {
        val.onclick = () => {
            let value= val.style.background,
                arr = value.split('/'),
                result=arr[arr.length-1].slice(0,-2);
            textureObjLoader.load(`./models/${result}`, function(texture){
                var mat = scene.getObjectByName( names[i], true).children[0].material;
                mat.map = texture;
                mat.needsUpdate = true;
            });
        };
    });
}
```

использование `.children[0]` в общем случае некорректно, однако я не стал с этим мудрить, по хорошему надо проехаться по всем мешам в объекте в поисках необходимого материала, т.к. в общем же случае материалы могут быть у отдельных объектов в модели разные и не одни. но это лирика, для Вашего примера код работает корректно

Так же может быть не оптимально каждый раз создавать новые текстуры при клике на кнопку, но тут палка о двух концах, все зависит от количества и размера текстур и от характера их использования в приложении (как часто они меняются итд)